# Selenium Webdriver with Java vs. c#

Tags: c#, java, selenium-webdriver

We have a Selenium WebDriver Framework developed using Java, TestNG and Jenkins. Now we got a new project developed by c# .net and the client also interested to restructure the same framework with c# instead of Java, but we don't have any knowledge on c# . Is there any limitation doing the same thing on c# or like any pros/cons on Selenium WebDriver with c# compared to java?

Comment: Realistically speaking, I would say the only *real* point that needs considering is that the language the tests are coded in should be the same as what the application is. This is so all developers and testers are able to understand, improve & debug the tests. No point having 1000's of tests that are coded in a language no one understands. There are no pro/con's to using one language than another. In terms of "not knowing anything about C#" -> now's the time to learn. ;)

Comment: I would be more concerned about TestNG vs NUnit.  NUnit does not support parallel execution where as TestNG does.  In my opinion, parallel execution is a deal breaker for successful enterprise level automation.  However, Gallio/MbUnit is a C# test library that does support parallelism BUT it is currently unmaintained!!  If I were to return back to C# automation, then TestNG would be the aspect I would miss the most

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved from a JUnit/Java WebDriver framework to a NUnit/C# one about three months ago. I was nervous about the transition, as I had no previous experience of C#, but have found it a lot easier than I could have imagined, and have had no major problems replicating similar functions in the new framework.

Sometimes I do miss Eclipse though, especially when Visual Studio (in my opinion) over complicates things or crashes when I edit a Page Object.